# Is there any way to revoke access from modules after a particular time?

Tags: odoo

We want to make the modules readonly. After clicking on the parent menus, all the submenus should also be readonly.
Tried `fields_view_get()` but there are too many forms to write the method for!
So is there any other way to do it. We are disabling the modules forever based on a particular date.
Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by read only when you talk about the modules and submenus ?

Comment: What do you mean by "disabling the modules" ? Do you want your module to stop working after some time ?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas Our requirement is too shift to keep the data in the old database as readonly. We  are migrating but want to keep  the old data/flow for now without giving the users any access to create new data after a particular date. Basically making all the forms as readonly.

Comment: @Majikat please check my comment above and give a solution if you have any

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that you can follow to achieve this will depend on what kind of access do your users have to your server. If they do not have access to the Settings menu, then what you can do is have a cron job run every X minutes that validates their subscription for your modules.

If the cron job finds that the their subscription is invalid and you want to make some menus unclickable or some views read only you can run the following query against the database to find out what views does a particular module create:

`select * from ir_model_data where module = 'your_module_name';`

The `ir_model_data` model actually contains all the keys for data your module contains. All the menus, views, groups etc you created using XML files (or not) are there.

Once you get all the records in your cursor you can `cr.fetchall()` and then loop on the return value. Each record will have a `model` and an `res_id`. When you see that you have a menu or a view that interests you you can set its `active` field to false to completely hide the view or menu.

When you loop on your results and find a field (that is a record that has `model='ir.model.fields'`, you can set the `readonly` field to True so that this field is readonly. You can do this for every field.

As you can understand this approach is not bullet proof. If your users have access to the settings (ie. admin rights) then you must not use Odoo's cron jobs and rather configure a cron job to be run from your Operating System to invoke an external Python script that will do the process described above.

Also, if you set the views/menus/fields readonly, they might be rendered as readonly on the web browser, but there is nothing stopping an end user for crafting a rpc request and sending inappropriate json data.

If the users have SSH access to your server there is not much you can do.